# istream operator to get whole line with spaces

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

How can I pass a whole string with spaces to my istream operator>>
I got something like:

```
friend std::istream&operator>>(std::istream&in, Movie&object) {
    std::cout << "Movie name: "; in >> object.name;
    std::cout << "Show time: "; in >> object.time;
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I pass a string with spaces to movie name the second word goes to show time. Is there a getline analog?
name and time are arrays of char if it matters

> char[xx]

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read whole lines from input.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can i do it if `object.name` is `char[xx]`?

Comment: You should rather use `std::string name;`

Comment: [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) will read into a `char` array, but prefer to use `std::string`. It will make your life whole orders of magnitude easier.

Comment: Side note: `cout` in a  `operator >>` is kinda gross. If you use `>>` to read from a file  or a socket or a whatever the program will dump lines of useless prompts into output.